# How to set columns 100% height within body using css

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to have ornamented border all along the right and left side of the document, but for some reason I have not managed to get the elements with those border ornaments reach 100% height.

What i have right now is:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-image: url("../img/bgtile.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 18px;
}
body:before {
  content: "";
  background: transparent url("../img/frame-ornament-left.png") repeat-y 11px 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
body:after {
  content: "";
  background: transparent url("../img/frame-ornament-right.png") repeat-y;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

And no matther what i try, those before and after elements always stay as high as viewport is. I've tried setting min-height to 100% on HTML element too, that indeed made html element as long as body, but those elements with ornaments in them still remain as high as viewport...

Comment: Unless you have a Sass->CSS compilation issues, **only post the compiled CSS** (and the necessary markup to reproduce the problem);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the body to `position: relative`, so it will be the context for the pseudo elements, instead of the `html`, and set `bottom: 0` to both pseudo elements:

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('../img/bgtile.png');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.content-demo { 
  height: 800px;
}

body:before {
  content: "";
  background: red;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
body:after {
  content: "";
  background: blue;
  width: 30px;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-demo"></div>
```

Comment: i do not need to set them to viewport height. They are already at that height and that is the issue that i am trying to describe here...

Comment: Is this what you've meant?

Comment: Yeah. thanks... didnt think i needed to set body to relative. Thanks. that did the trick.

Comment: Great. It was annoying :)